# AHK GUI card view flow issue

Tags: user-interface, view, autohotkey

```
Gui, 1:Add, Tab, x-11 y-21 w493 h405 vCardTabs, Tab1|Tab2|Tab3

Gui, Tab, Tab1 
    Gui, 1:Add, Text,, This is tab 1
    Gui, 1:Add, Button, x352 y330 w100 h30 , Next

Gui, Tab, Tab2
    Gui, 1:Add, Text,, This is tab 2
    Gui, 1:Add, Button, x352 y330 w100 h30 , Next
    Gui, 1:Add, Button, x242 y330 w90 h30 , Back

Gui, Tab, Tab3  
    Gui, 1:Add, Text,, This is tab 3
    Gui, 1:Add, Button, x242 y330 w90 h30 , Back

Gui, 1:Show, x-1246 y259 h379 w479, Card view gui
Return

1GuiClose:
ExitApp

ButtonBack:
Send ^+{TAB}
return

ButtonNext:
Send ^{TAB}
return
```

I have created a card view layout in AHK however I have a problem, I have used a method of creating a set of tabs, and hiding the tabs from user view just outside of the viewable program window, however users are able to send commands to the window to cycle through the tabs e.g <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

I am wondering if there is a better way of forming this type of GUI and have more control, e.g only pass onto the next tab (panel?) with button press

if there is some type of panel view that I have missed that can be added to avoid this issue it would help me alot thankyou

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to prevent users from cycling through the tabs with ^tab ^+tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went under the assumption that you wanted to disable ctrl+tab and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> for your script but still have the buttons cycle through the tabs.

Below you'll find that I override the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+... hotkeys and not allow the function to be sent if your gui is active, otherwise it sends the desired keystroke (important because we want that to work in other tabbed applications).

For cycling through the tabs w/o <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+... hotkeys, I get the name of the currently selected tab, and use GuiControl, Choose... to select the next/previous tab.

Finally, at the stop of your script, I demonstrated that you can name your guis and set them as defaults.

```
; you can name your guis vs using numbers
Gui, MyCustomName_:Default ; setting as default will tell all controls below it to use that gui
Gui, Add, Tab, w493 h405 vCardTabs, Tab1|Tab2|Tab3

Gui, Tab, Tab1 
    Gui, Add, Text,, This is tab 1
    Gui, Add, Button, x352 y330 w100 h30 , Next

Gui, Tab, Tab2
    Gui, Add, Text,, This is tab 2
    Gui, Add, Button, x352 y330 w100 h30 , Next
    Gui, Add, Button, x242 y330 w90 h30 , Back

Gui, Tab, Tab3  
    Gui, Add, Text,, This is tab 3
    Gui, Add, Button, x242 y330 w90 h30 , Back

Gui, Show, y259 h379 w479, Card view gui
return

MyCustomName_GuiClose:
ExitApp

$^tab::
{
    IfWinNotActive, Card view gui
        SendInput, ^{tab}
    return
}
$^+tab::
{
    IfWinNotActive, Card view gui
        SendInput, ^+{tab}
    return
}

ButtonBack:
GuiControlGet, name,, CardTabs
if (name == "Tab2") {
    GuiControl, Choose, CardTabs, Tab1
} else if (name == "Tab3") {
    GuiControl, Choose, CardTabs, Tab2
}
return

ButtonNext:
GuiControlGet, name,, CardTabs
if (name == "Tab1") {
    GuiControl, Choose, CardTabs, Tab2
} else if (name == "Tab2") {
    GuiControl, Choose, CardTabs, Tab3
}
return
```

Hope this helps!